# I start using Stack Overflow over HTTPS, and later it switches to HTTP

Tags: bug, ssl

I start using Stack Overflow by going to https://stackoverflow.com. All is well. However, if I then click the Stack Overflow "Top Questions" button in the toolbar (Stack Overflow logo), that hyperlink is *not* HTTPS, so browsing the site reverts to HTTP.

Comment: Thanks all for pointing out duplicate.